# Declaration mistake in C with return value

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, return, declaration

Is there a reason this kind of declaration is wrong in C?

```
short foo()
{
   short x,y,z;
   y=24;
   z = x + y;
   return z; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The declarations are not wrong *per se*, but there are issues with the code:

- In modern C, `short foo(void)` is preferred over `short foo()`. The former says the function takes no parameters. The latter leaves it flexible, which involves a number of issues that can allow bugs to occur.
- In `z = x + y;`, `x` has not been given a value. The behavior of the code is then undefined. (This is due to a special rule that using an object with automatic storage duration that has neither been given a value nor had its address taken has behavior not defined by the C standard.)

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `z` will be undefined behavior because you don't initialize the value of `x` variable in this function. The return value of this function will be inconsistent, sometimes it will be 24, sometimes it will be another value.

Comment: It is worse than `z` merely having unspecified values. Per C 2018 6.3.2.1 2, the entire behavior is not defined by the C standard: `z` could have any value, a trap could occur, the call to the function could be removed during optimization, and more.

Comment: So in this case changing the function signature to
short foo(short x) and x is removed as a stack variable should solve the problem?

Comment: @JDoe yeah. You can do that way. `x` will be removed from stack  of function foo. And the caller will control the `x` variable itself. Caller need to initialize `x` as well.

Comment: short foo(short a)
{
   short b,c;
   b=10;

   c = a + b;

   return c; 
}

So this will have no error.